# Google Sheet Query - Repeating certain Columns

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with Data tab and Report tab. I use Query in Report tab and the range is from the Data tab. I learned that to repeat certain columns you'd have to combine more than 1 query inside a curly bracket. (Sample below, for the report I would need column V to AA to be repeated on the report).

```
={QUERY(Data!$A:$AG,"select D,C,AF,V,W,X,Y,Z,AA where AF=ForReport"),QUERY(Data!$A:$AG,"select V,W,X,Y,Z,AA,F,J where AF=ForReport")}
```

Is this method the best method and safe? I'm worried that the result from each query could fail to line-up or match. I didn't sort and both queries use the same condition except the columns to select but it's hard to prove if combined queries messed up the report data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula looks fine to me. You could also use CHOOSECOLS.

```
=QUERY(CHOOSECOLS(DATA!A:AG,4,3,32,22,23,24,25,26,27,22,23,24,25,26,27,6,10),"where Col3='ForReport'")
```

Comment: Hi Z, unfortunately it's not working. =QUERY(CHOOSECOLS(Data!$A:$AH,4,3,32,22,23,24,25,26,27,22,23,24,25,26,27,6,10,6,8,34,34,34,34,30,31,34,1,28,29,34,34,34,34,34,34,34),"where Col32=1234"). I tried "where AF=1234" and even tried changing the format of column AF from Automatic to Plain Text. This method doesn't seem to work with WHERE

Comment: Try to remove the QUERY and see what the CHOOSECOLS formula is returning

Comment: `=QUERY(CHOOSECOLS(Data!$A:$AH,4,3,32,22,23,24,25,26,27,22,23,24,25,26,27,6,10,6,8,34,34,34,34,30,31,34,1,28,29,34,34,34,34,34,34,34),"where Col32=1234")` Hi Z, if query is removed, the entire range/table `Data!$A:$AH` is displayed. If query is there only row 1 or the table headers are displayed. I think the `where AF=1234` is returning no result except row 1. Note that Col32 header/cell value is 1234 but so are other cells in Col32

Comment: I got it working. I just started with Query but after a couple of headaches and trials, I found out that query only works with either text or numeric but not both. So I had to use TO_TEXT to convert the range to text. Also, the `Col` number in `Where` clause actually refers to the Nth column specified/chosen by the query or ChooseCols I didn't notice this before and I used `where Col32` when I should be using `where Col3`.